# Using registry.php to store objects

Tags: php, singleton, registry

My website at the moment runs like this,

index.php

- includes config.php->

config.php

- sets variable, $siteRegistry = Registry::singleton();
- also disects url and creates new object depending what url says, so www.site.com/login creates new login object.

loginObject

- created inside config.php
- creates new loginModel

loginModel

- Needs to access $siteRegistry but shows following error,

Notice: Undefined variable: siteRegistry in F:\Projects\application\models\loginModel.php on line 37

This is line 37 -

```
$siteRegistry->storeObject("PDOExtender", "DBO");
```

I believe the problem is that it can't find the $siteRegistry variable from config.php, does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: have you included `config.php` in `loginModel`? what is the scope of `$siteRegistry`? is it global?

Comment: show me previous 36 lines, and I'll try to understand them.

Comment: well the error basically says, that $siteRegistry does not exsist. But - without more code as @OZ_ said, its more or less very difficult to help you on this where exactly your mistake is that this error occurs.

Comment: By the way, read, why Singleton is bad pattern: http://misko.hevery.com/code-reviewers-guide/flaw-brittle-global-state-singletons/
or this: http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/08/by-miko-hevery-so-you-join-new-project.html
or video: http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2008/11/clean-code-talks-global-state-and.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$siteRegistry = Registry::singleton();
```

As Registry (what ever it might be) is a singleton there is no need to use this $siteRegistry variable as a global.
In fact you should always call `Registry::singleton` inside each function you want to use it.
If that is to long just create a small wrapper function:

```
function reg() {
    return Registry::singleton();
}
```

The whole purpose of singleton objects is that there is always only one of them at a time, so you can always get them again during the programs execution without having to use variables.